# How C stores different data types in the memory?

Tags: c, memory, assembly

I am learning assembly (for MIPS) and I know that every memory call brings a 32bits word. I also know that in C there are some data types that don´t require 32 bits. For example a char only needs 8 bits of memory and a int 16bits. So my question is does a char in C use 32bits in the memory? Or only 8 bits? And if it is only 8 bits if the CPU loads from memory an address that cointains a char won´t it receive a 32 bits word? I am a bit confused about this since I was always told that everything is stored as a 32bits word in the memory.

For one side makes sense to store a char on a 8bits block so save space.

Comment: "I am learning assembly (for MIPS) and I know that every memory call brings a 32bits word." - No it doesn't. MIPS has lb and sb for 8 bits, and lh and sh for 16 bits.

Answer (score 2):

You are misinformed.  MIPS is a byte-addressable CPU, so each 'cell' of memory holds only 8 bits.  Each read (or write) instruction can access 1, 2, or 4 bytes at a time to access 8, 16, or 32 bits (on MIPS32 -- with MIPS64, you can also access 8 bytes/64 bits in a single read or write).